# Modify database entries on mouseover

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a go at creating a notification system for my Rails web app. The header of the site has a bell icon that'll have a red bubble pop up if you have new notifications and clicking on the bell gives you a list of all your most recent notifications.

What I'd like though is to update the notifications 'dismissed' boolean value in the database from false to true when it is hovered over with the mouse. I'm guessing some kind of AJAX/JS could be used but I'm not very confident with those languages so some assistance would be great!

```
#The template for the header
<li class="notify">
 <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-bell-o" id="notificationmenu" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>
   <% if @newnotifications > 0 %>     
    <div class="notification-bubble"> <%= @newnotifications %> </div>       
   <% end %> 
   <ul class="dropdown dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-Labelledby="notificationmenu">
    <% current_user.notifications.where("appear_at < ?", Time.now).order(appear_at: :desc).limit(4).each do |n| %>
      <li><div class="notification">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"><%= n.image %></div>
          <div class="col-md-9"><%= n.content %></div>
          </div>
          </div></li>
      <% end %>

   </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: What is the ajax you have tried and how did it not work for you? (what was the error message or unexpected behaviour)? what happened when you googled for "ajax rails" and why were the results unsatisfactory? What other searches did you try? Show us that you've made some effort, and tell us what you did so we don't duplicate that effort :)

Comment: Well it seemed that I'll be having to use the $.ajax command in jQuery to update the database but I'm having trouble understanding the documentation - what options to pass into it and whether or not it'll work when I hover the mouse over the notification...

Comment: yes, but seriously - lots of people have done this before, so you'd expect to be able to find a tutorial on it if you google and add the "rails" keyword... the tutorial would show you what to add to the ajax query (by example)

Comment: eg http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html